# php displayes wrong data from db

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display the highest temperature and the day that temperature was recorded. It displays the correct temperature but the wrong date. I don't know if I am going crazy, but I am quite sure it worked just fine before. Here is the query request.

```
$statment = $pdo->prepare('SELECT MAX(temperature), date FROM 4pmweather ');
$statment->execute();
$products = $statment->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$max_temp = $products[0]['MAX(temperature)'];
$max_temp = floatval(round($max_temp,1));
$date_of_max_temp = $products[0]['date'];

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($products);
echo '</pre>';
```

Here is what var_dump() returns as I said it shows the right temperature but the wrong date. i don't know if that matters but I am using phpmyadimin.

```
array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
    ["MAX(temperature)"]=>
    float(27.05)
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2022-04-30 16:59:02"
  }
}
```

[image: [![enter image description here][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDnzl.png]

Comment: And if you look through the table at every row that has 27.05 in the temperature column. What does it say in the date column?

Comment: Hello, it shows 2022-05-11. I will try to include pic of table in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something this:

```
$statment = $pdo->prepare('SELECT temperature, date FROM 4pmweather WHERE temperature=(SELECT MAX(temperature) FROM 4pmweather)');
```

Otherwise you will get the max value from the temperature column and the first id.

Just note that if max temperature is not unique it might return multiple rows. Then you could add `LIMIT 1` to the query:

```
SELECT temperature, date FROM 4pmweather WHERE temperature=(SELECT MAX(temperature) FROM 4pmweather) LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you, I am not quite sure why my query didn't work as intended

Comment: It's because it will return the max value, and the first id. You didn't actually ask for the row with the maximum temperature, but the value of it.

Comment: I see, thank you once more. I will add the limit thank you for the advice.

Comment: I edited my answer, make sure you put the limit OUTSIDE that parenthesis.. like I didn't first :-P

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the row with the maximum temperature, order by that column and use `LIMIT`.

```
SELECT temperature, date
FROM 4pmweather
ORDER BY temperature DESC
LIMIT 1
```